# Extra borders for th

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with HTML tables, the `th` with `colspan=3` shouldn't have border top and bottom but it does. What is the reason?

I've removed the borders all together with `border: 0px solid black`.

I've also created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6v348y5/).

**Screenshots:**

- [Chrome 62.0 on Windows Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6FCs.png)
- [Inspect Element Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWNsQ.png)

**PS:** I know tables should not be used for layouts I'm just trying to learn how tables work.

**Update:**
I know that when I don't use `border-collapse: collapse`, these extra borders do not show up, but need to use `border-collapse` for the rest of my table.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body {height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0px;
    }
table {width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
table, td, th, .box{ border:0px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    }
.main {width: 980px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-width: 1px;}
 /* header */
.main .header { height: 150px;
     border-bottom-width: 1px;}
.main .header td{ width: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;}
.main .header td img {float: right;}
.main .header td img[src*='flag'] {margin: 5px 3px 0px 4px;}

 /* header */
 /* Nav */
.main .nav {
    height: 32px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;}
.main .nav th {
    width: 25%;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
.main .nav th:nth-last-child(1) {
    border-right-width: 0px;
}
.main .nav th:first-letter{ text-transform: uppercase;
color: red;}
.main .nav th:hover { background-color: black; 
                color:white;}

/* Content */
.main .Content {
    padding: 70px 130px 20px;
}               
.main .Content td {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-width: 1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="main">
        <tr>
            <td class="header"> 
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="image/logo.jpg"></td>
                        <th>Site Name</th>
                        <td><img src="image/flag-nl.png" /><img src="image/flag-us.png" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="nav">
                <table>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Support</th>
                    <th>services</th>
                    <th>about us</th>                   
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Content">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <th>2</th>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <th>2</th>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

Comment: That `<th>` doesn’t have a border. What is the expected result?

Comment: There is no border for me, Firefox 56.0.2.

Comment: I've viewing on Chrome  62.0 on Windows, I've added a screenshot.

Comment: Added Inspect Screenshot

Comment: @pjsofts:  I mean it's not possible to remove just `th`s border with `border-collapse: collapse`. If possible, set 1px border in the same color as background.

Comment: @panther Why do you start your sentence with "I mean"? Nice hack, but I'm looking for the reason.

Comment: @pjsofts: It's not general hack, just for this example with one-color background. Try to check into HTML/CSS specs, I have no time to read and find it there. When you have collapsed borders, it isn't allowed to put border to just a part of cells in table. If it's possible to change HTML markup, it's possible to find any 'clean' solution. Your HTML markup is bad for the target you want to reach. And what about my 'mean' word? Maybe there should be 'I think'? :-)

Comment: checked the specification, it says it should be possible to have partly specified borders in the collapse mode. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders

Comment: A duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427442/strange-behaviour-with-border-collapse-and-colspan

Answer (score 2):

try removing this: `border-collapse: collapse;`

Comment: I need to use border-collapse for the rest of the table.

Answer (score -5):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin:0;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      table {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      table, td, .box { 
        border:0px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .main { 
        width: 980px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        border-width: 1px;
        border: none;
      }
      /* header */
      .main .header { 
        height: 150px;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
      }
      .main .header td { 
        width: 150px;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      .main .header td img {
        float: right;
      }
      .main .header td img[src*='flag'] {
        margin: 5px 3px 0px 4px;
      }

      /* header */
      /* Nav */
      .main .nav {
        height: 32px;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;}
      .main .nav th {
        width: 25%;
        border-right-width: 1px;
      }
      .main .nav th:nth-last-child(1) {
        border-right-width: 0px;
      }
      .main .nav th:first-letter{ text-transform: uppercase;
        color: red;
      }
      .main .nav th:hover { background-color: black;
        color:white;
      }

      /* Content */
        .main .Content {
        padding: 70px 130px 20px;
      }
      .main .Content td {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border-width: 1px;
      }
      .nav .Content tr {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
  </style>
</head>
```

Site Name
              
            
          
        
      
      
        
          
            Product
            Support
            services
            about us
          
        
      
      
        
          
            
              1
              2
              3
            
             
            
              1
              2
              3

Comment: Actually, doesn't.

Comment: Due to the css of border-bottom-width for .main .header and .main .nav  , The border does not hide

Comment: Removing any explanation and leaving just a block of code actually makes your answer worse.